# How to add a subtitle in class article in Latex?

Tags: latex, subtitle, article, document-class

I am writing a report in Latex and my document class must be article. I want to add some additional text under my title but I can't find anything that would correspond to a subtitle command. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\title {Title}
\author{Name}
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\title {Title}
\author{Name}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\Large Whatever Subtitle you want\par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\maketitle

test

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Hopefully, I found a very easy and quick solution:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\title {Title \\[1ex] \large Subtitle}
\author{Name}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This will mess with the pdf meta data if used in combination with hyperref and without paragraphs the line spacing will be wrong.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you! [My reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219399/49683). By the way, many compliments for your [latex] silver badge, lots of contributions and help here and there, that's great :)